# How to get CruiseControl.NET working with Mercurial: "Source control failure (GetModifications)"

Tags: mercurial, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I'm trying to set up CruiseControl.NET 1.5.7256.1 for automatic builds. My project is stored in Mercurial, and I'm using the following `ccnet.config`:

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
    <project name="Slider" webURL="http://localhost/ccnet">
        <triggers>
            <intervalTrigger seconds="3600" />
        </triggers>
        <sourcecontrol type="hg" autoGetSource="true">
            <executable>C:\Python26\Scripts\hg.bat</executable>
            <repo>c:\repos\slider</repo>
            <workingDirectory>c:\ccnet\slider</workingDirectory>
        </sourcecontrol>
        <tasks>
            <msbuild>
                <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe</executable>
                <workingDirectory>c:\ccnet\slider</workingDirectory>
                <projectFile>Slider.sln</projectFile>
                <buildArgs>/noconsolelogger /p:Configuration=Debug /v:diag</buildArgs>
                <targets>Slider</targets>
                <timeout>900</timeout>
                <logger>C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
            </msbuild>
        </tasks>
    </project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

But when I force a build, I get this error:

```
[Slider:WARN] Source control failure (GetModifications): Source control operation failed: < was unexpected at this time.
. Process command: C:\Python26\Scripts\hg.bat log -r 0:123 --template <modification><node>{node|short}</node><author>{author|user}</author><date>{date|rfc822date}</date><desc>{desc|escape}</desc><rev>{rev}</rev><email>{author|email|obfuscate}</email><files>{files}</files></modification> --noninteractive
[Slider:INFO] Integration complete: Exception - 12/2/2010 1:19:08 PM
```

The error is presumably caused by the unquoted angle brackets in the `--template` parameter, but how can I make CC.NET put quotes around that parameter?

===============

Here's hg.bat:

```
@echo off
rem Windows Driver script for Mercurial

setlocal
set HG=%~f0

rem Use a full path to Python (relative to this script) as the standard Python
rem install does not put python.exe on the PATH...
rem %~dp0 is the directory of this script

%~dp0..\python "%~dp0hg" %*
endlocal
```

Comment: what does the contents of hg.bat look like?

Comment: It calls the Python interpreter to run Hg. IIRC it was created by the Python package installer. I can post the contents on Monday.

Comment: Well, I ended up switching to TeamCity, which works just fine with Hg and is also easy to configure. It'd still be nice to know what was going wrong with CC.NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm successfully using CruiseControl.NET 1.5.7256.1 with Mercurial installed from this [msi](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg-winbuild/downloads/mercurial-1.7.2-x86.msi), using full path of `hg.exe` as the `executable` value.

In `project\core\sourcecontrol\Mercurial\Mercurial.cs` the template is used like this:

```
buffer.AddArgument("--template", HistoryTemplate)
```

and will be formatted for the command line like this:

```
string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", arg, separator, StringUtil.AutoDoubleQuoteString(value))
```

where the separator is `" "`, and `AutoDoubleQuoteString` will quote the template, so this can't be the cause of the error.

**UPDATE 1**

Actually, `AutoDoubleQuoteString` **should** quote the template, but in the current version doesn't do it. Also, even if the build succeeds when using `hg.exe`, running the actual command line in a command prompt returns the same error.

**UPDATE 2**

[CruiseControl.NET 1.6.7981.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccnet/files/CruiseControl.NET%20Releases/CruiseControl.NET%201.6/) was just released (see [release notes](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/CCNet+1.6+Release+Notes)), and since the template is now passed as a file, it works just fine (at least on my PC).

Comment: Ah, hmm. Must be the way I have Hg installed, then.